# Ensure the type on the Action to implement type ILogger

Tags: c#, serilog

The following code wraps a call to Serilog logging with a using statement to decorate the call.  I wish to ensure that only type ILogger can be passed in the Action.
_logger implements ILogger.

```
 public class AuditLogger : IAuditLogger
{
    public void Audit(Action logger)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("EventType", "Audit"))
        {
            logger.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

_auditLogger.Audit(()=>_logger.Information("Edit User {UserId}",id));
//_auditLogger implements ILogger
```

If there is a smarter approach than what I'm doing feel free to offer it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't "passing in" ILogger, you're passing in a lambda that can do any random thing.

You could do something like:

```
Audit(ILogger logger, Action<ILogger> action)
{
   action(logger);
}

Audit(_logger, x => x.Information(...));
```

Or if AuditLogger is constructed independently, you can pass in _logger into the constructor and just the action into the method.